# How to simply package the source code of Apache IoTDB into jar package?

Tags: directory, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Does anyone have experience on how to package the source code of Apache IoTDB into a jar package? I know that direct compilation will be capable, but I cannot find which is the executable jar package in the given document since many are non-executable jars. Anyone know which package to start for packing jar package?

How to deal this question ? Someone help please.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the compressed package in the distribution/target directory of Apache IoTDB. Just decompress and execute it will help you to pack up a jar package using source code.